# How to resolve the following import?

Tags: java, junit, junit4

Just add some Junit4 test cases,

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
```

but it prompts some errors until I changed to 
`@org.junit.Test` from `@Test`

What should I do if I would like to just use `@Test`?

Answer (score 2):

You need to also

```
import org.junit.Test;
```

Answer (score 0):

`Test` is not part of `org.junit.Assert`. It is rather part of `org.junit`.

So it should suffice to do:

```
import org.junit.Test;
```

Answer (score 0):

[`@Test`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Test.html) is an annotation class, and you need to import it as such. Including the package, it's name is `org.junit.Test`

Thus, you need to add this to your imports:

```
import org.junit.Test;
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is `@Test` annotations defined in the code from testng  i.e. `org.testng.annotations.Test` package then the for defining @Test annotation of junit you will have to write `@org.junit.Test` unless you delete the import statement of the testng package `org.testng.annotations.Test`